# tricky gotHtml can't load contents

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have an excellent "gotHtml" code that give me in my php page the content of other php pages. but when i want to call these "href" from "index.php" , and not " service.php " who works fine, i cant load the the page  and the content, any ideas?

```
/here is the php part
<p id="serv-tabs">
<a href="#serv/acse">Accounting Services</a><br/>
<a href="#serv/compA">Company Administration</a><br/>
 ........
 ........</p>

<div id="serv-content"> 
.....
</div>


/here is the script
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#serv-tabs a").click(function() {
    var page= this.hash.substr(1);
    $.get(page+".php",function(gotHtml) {
        $("#serv-content").html(gotHtml);
    });
    return false;
});});
```

Comment: What exactly is failing? Are any errors being raised in the console? Also, you can just use `$("#serv-content").load(page + ".php")` instead of `$.get` and then specifying the callback function.

Comment: when i am at page service.php i click on my href and then my script calls the content i want, but when i click an href from another page to navigate me at the previous page "service#xxxx.php" fails.

Comment: @LefterisLivanos I have provided you with solution, it doesn't work, I've tested and works ...

Comment: Could you clarify what the links you're generating are?  That is, what's on index.php and service.php, and which ones work/don't work?  Please include the anchors, and file paths as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry my English are not good, let explain ..

Comment: I have a page called service.php and i have a ul with some li and each of li add some contents into the page "service.php". this part works fine____ now i have a ul with some li in my index.php and i want to click the li and navigate me at page service.php and add the content i  click at li too.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `substr()` there, you should split your page name by `/` and use second value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#serv-tabs a").click(function() {
        var page = this.hash.split('/');
        $.get(page[1]+".php",function(gotHtml) {
            $("#serv-content").html(gotHtml);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I'm guessing you are loading `service.php` with same principle, in that case you should reinitialize the binds in order to bind clicks on new elements:

```
function reBind(element, content){
    $("#"+element+" a").click(function() {
        var page = this.hash.split('/');
        $.get(page[1]+".php",function(gotHtml) {
            $("#"+content).html(gotHtml);
        });
        return false;
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#page-tabs a").click(function() { // assuming your service.php is called in same way like subpages in services are called, I've added page-tabs as main pages
        var page = this.hash.split('/');
        $.get(page[1]+".php",function(gotHtml) {
            $("#page-content").html(gotHtml);
        }).success(function(){
            if(page[1] == 'service'){
                reBind('serv-tabs', 'serv-content');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: the problem is that my js works fine only in one page, the page that call the content i want, the problem is tha when i want to navigate from another page to the service.php and the content i want fails

Comment: I have a page called service.php and i have a ul with some li and each of li add some contents into the page "service.php". this part works fine____ now i have a ul with some li in my index.php and i want to click the li and navigate me at page service.php and add the content i click at li too

Comment: I think I understood you, I hope you will understand me. After you receive `service.php` with jQuery you have to rebind the click on links. Like I've shown above.

Comment: U are great thank u but i cant make it happen, what i want is very stupid and i have another way to make it happen, thanks alot all of u